# Why Java Function default method "andthen" type parameter is just <V>?

Tags: java, generics

In the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html), I see:

```
default <V> Function<T,V> andThen(Function<? super R,? extends V> after)
```

Why does it say `<V>`, rather than `<V, R>`?

Comment: There isn't? There's `andThen(Function<? super R, ? extends V>`, there's no bare `<V>` anywhere?

Comment: Can you format the code in the question? Some of it is being interpreted as HTML tags, so the rendered output is missing information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I tried to edit the question to avoid formatting issues and ask the question clearly.

Answer (score 3):

`R` is defined at the level of the `Function` interface, not at the level of the `andThen` method call.  You don't need to include type parameters that are part of the type that has the method.